# WiFi and Bluetooth will not work on Dell Studio XPS 1645

Tags: wireless, dell, bluetooth, internet-connection, dell-studio-xps-16

Today I acquired a Dell XPS 1645. Ubuntu seems to run alright on it however The bluetooth is not detected and the WiFi doesn't work. The WiFi is especially weird because I actually have the restricted driver enabled  for it. It also worked for a short while when I first booted into Ubuntu however now there isn't even an option to enable wireless.

Both 'etho' and 'lo' return 'no wireless extentions' when running iwconfig and 'sudo ip link set wlan0' returns 'cannot find device "wlan0".

It uses the Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY which seems to be contained in plenty of certified Ubuntu systems.

If anyone could possibly help me out with this I'd deeply appreciate it. I've not had to return to Windows for a good while and it's not something I want to have to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please hook up the ethernet temporarily and do:

```
    sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
    sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Reboot and let us have your report.

Comment: That seems to have solved everything, thank you very much! Software Sources is showing that I'm not using the proprietary drivers and instead using a manually installed one. Hopefully this will continue to work. Is it still possible to mark problems as solved?

Comment: I should also note that although I wasn't expecting it to, this didn't do a thing for the Bluetooth.

Comment: I know little about bluetooth. I suggest you post a new question. They only let me fiddle with easy stuff here.

Comment: Thought I should say that I just turned on the laptop and the WiFi no longer works. Either this is only a temporary fix or some sort of update has messed with the drivers.

Comment: Does the wireless start if you do: sudo modprobe b43? If so, please do: sudo su; echo b43 >> /etc/modules; exit.